# Get the value of an element from an array in an array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, key-value

I searched but couldnt find the answer to this; I assume its pretty easy but I cant get it right. Trying to get the value of `amount` here:

```
let fruit = [
{"prices":{"price":{"amount":4.97,"unit":"ea","quantity":1},"wasPrice":null}
]
```

I have loop and I tried something like this; but didnt work:

```
keyPrice = Object.keys(fruit[i].prices.price); 
console.log(keyPrice['amount'])
//this is giving me undefined result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet is syntactically malformed (3 opening, 2 closing braces).

If that's just a typo, `Object.keys(...)` produces an array of property *names*. It would be set to `['amount', 'unit', 'quantity']`.

Also, `i` should be initialized to `0`.

What you intend is:

```
let i=0;
let keyPrice = fruit[i].prices.price; // Rename the variable!
console.log(keyPrice['amount']);
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you miss one curly brace } after null

```
let fruit = [
        {"prices":
            {"price":
                {"amount":4.97,"unit":"ea","quantity":1}
            ,"wasPrice":null}
            }
        ]
```

and this for amount value

```
 fruit[0].prices.price.amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `dig` function:

```js
function dig(obj, func){
  let v;
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(let i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      v = obj[i];
      if(typeof v === 'object'){
        dig(v, func);
      }
      else{
        func(v, i, obj);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    for(let i in obj){
      v = obj[i];
      if(typeof v === 'object'){
        dig(v, func);
      }
      else{
        func(v, i, obj);
      }
    }
  }
}
let fruit = [
  {
    prices:{
      price:{
        amount:4.97,
        unit:'ea',
        quantity:1
      },
      wasPrice:null
    }
  }
];
dig(fruit, (v, i, obj)=>{
  if(i === 'amount')console.log(v);
});
```